# Turn Debian into Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-sources, debian, arm

I'd like to turn Debian into Ubuntu server 16.04.
Problem is that its running on ARM9 32bit processor with some archaic hardware and I don't want to make new installation.

How should I modify /etc/apt/sources.list to be able to install new software preserving old drivers?

Maybe I should keep old kernel and just install side packages that do not require kernel modifications?

---

this is what I get from 
cat /proc/cpuinfo

```
Processor   : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS    : 183.09
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5
Cache type  : write-back
Cache clean : cp15 c7 ops
Cache lockdown  : format C
Cache format    : Harvard
I size      : 32768
I assoc     : 4
I line length   : 32
I sets      : 256
D size      : 32768
D assoc     : 4
D line length   : 32
D sets      : 256

Hardware    : Oxsemi NAS
```

Comment: The old 'drivers' will be wiped out anyway when you install an Ubuntu kernel. How skilled are you at apt, apt-pinning/marking, and deconflicting apt conflicts? Because you will gain much experience at those skills while you complete this project. I gently suggest you try such a transition on a different machine, in a VM, before embarking upon bare metal.

Comment: Bad idea. ARM based devices usually have an OS specially optimized for them. A regular Ubuntu, most likely, just won't work. If there is an Ubuntu image for that hardware, you'll still need to wipe and install. I doubt any apt magic or VM testing is relevant here.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu over other Linux distros without loss of data in `/home` with relative ease. Since Ubuntu and Debian use the same package manager and often the same packages you can even create a list of all installed (non-essential) packages and then install them again after the distro switch.

Comment: What should I put in sources.list for arm?